# send data from one page to another using Query String

Tags: jquery

I have two HTML pages I want to pass data from one page to another page using a query string. I tried this way but it doesn't work, what might be the problem can anyone help out.

```js
$(function () {
   $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {

    var pack = document.getElementById('pack-val').value;
    var info = document.getElementById('info').value;

     var url = "packages-style-1.html?&pack=" + pack + "&download=" + info;
     window.location.href = url;
     });
  });

 var queryString = new Array();
        $(function () {
    if (queryString.length == 0) {
      if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
         var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
         for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
           var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
             var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
              queryString[key] = value;
       }
        }
       }
            if (queryString["pack"] != null && queryString["download"]) {
                var data = "<u>Values from QueryString</u><br /><br />";
               pack += "<b>Pack:</b> " + queryString["pack"] + " <b>Download:</b> " + queryString["info"];
                $("#lblData").html(data);
            }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="at-intenet-package" id="pack">
  <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
  <td class="at-int-speedname" id="pack-val">
   <h2 class="at-IntHdr">Value Pack</h2>
   <ul>
   <li><b>768Kbps</b> Download Speed</li>
               <li><b>384Kbps</b> Upload Speed</li>
   </ul>
   </td>
   <td class="at-int-dl1">
     <h2 class="at-IntHdr">6.2<span class="time-sep">hrs</span></h2>
   <span class="todownload">to download*</span>
   </td>
   <td class="at-int-dl2">
     <h2 class="at-IntHdr">55<span class="time-sep">min</span></h2>
     <span class="todownload">to download*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="at-int-dl3">
   <h2 class="at-IntHdr">11<span class="time-sep">min</span></h2>
   <span class="todownload">to download*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="at-int-price" id="info">
    <h2 class="at-IntHdr"><span>$</span>17.95<span class="per-month"> per mon*</span></h2>
   <span class="check-info">12 Month Pricing<br>No Contract Required<br>Equipment Priced Separately</span>
     </td>
     <td class="at-int-check"><a href="check.html" id="btnQueryString" class="at-int-btn dark-btn">Check Availability</a></td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

when I click on check Availability button the data send to another page i want only first and last  info.

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2: Expected o/p after sent Data.

[image]

Comment: you can't pass values across pages using `jquery/js` with this approach. use `localstorage` instead

Comment: can you please explain in detail.

Comment: How are you getting anything with `.value` property? You don't have any form controls like `<input>` your code as it stands doesn't work for `info` or `pack-val`. Name the actual variables you want to transfer to second page. *"I tried this way but it doesn't work, ..."* Please explain what exactly what you tried. All I see is cut n paste jQuery that doesn't even match its HTML very well. BTW, `queryString['pack']` and `queryString['info']` is wrong syntax for an array but correct for an object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to get the contents of the pack-val and info elements. It is possible to send query string parameters to another page like you are doing as long as you are setting the window.location.href like you are doing. However, I believe your values for pack-val and info will always be "undefined".

Are you trying to send the html contents of those elements to the next page? If so that is not advised as you will need to escape and unescape the contents and generally it is not good to pass html content back and forth as query strings.

It would be better to store the package details in an array or variable and just pass the selected package key back and forth.